# Import error when dockerizing a project using zerorpc in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, zeromq

I'm migrating a project to python on docker for a better "facility" for development. 
Ut's a project that runs with python 2.7, Django 1.6.8 and several RPC dependencies

I find myself with a crash of the application with this stacktrace that I can't find the missing module **(No module named coros)**.

I'm thinking it should either be an addiction problem related to a version that is not good or an addiction installed on the default bone but not on the docker bone. 
Do you have any ideas or suggestions to correct this problem?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2

WORKDIR /var/www
RUN echo "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/zeromq:/release-stable/Debian_9.0/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN wget https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:/messaging:/zeromq:/release-stable/Debian_9.0/Release.key -O- | apt-key add
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install libzmq3-dev  libev-dev -y 


RUN apt-get install -y  bash \
            git \
            default-libmysqlclient-dev \
            libldap2-dev \
            libsasl2-dev \
            libssl-dev \
            python-gevent \
            python-gevent-websocket \
            build-essential \
            python-dev \
            locales

RUN pip install django-debug-toolbar==1.2.1
RUN apt-get install libevent-dev -y 
RUN apt-get install python-all-dev -y 
RUN pip install gevent
RUN pip install greenlet
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
ADD requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip install pyzmq
```

My requirements file

```
crispy-forms-foundation==0.2.3.1
django-crispy-forms==1.3.2
Django==1.6.8
django-auth-ldap==1.1.4
django-pipeline==1.3.14
iso8601==0.1.8
MySQL-python==1.2.5
nameko==2.1.2
python-ldap==2.4.10
python-memcached==1.53
pytz==2013.8
django-widget-tweaks==1.3
Babel==1.3
django-braces==1.2.2
PyReact==0.2.0
raven==3.2.1
djangorestframework==3.1.3
django-statsd-mozilla==0.3.12
boto==2.8.0
libthumbor==1.0.1
Pillow==2.5.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.2.2
South==1.0.1
zerorpc==0.4.4
requests>=2.7.0,<3.0.0
python-updict==0.1.2
graphene==0.10.2
beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
ciso8601==1.0.2
```

Error traceback

```
app_1       | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
app_1       |     self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
app_1       |     return self.application(environ, start_response)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
app_1       |     self.load_middleware()
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware
app_1       |     mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_by_path
app_1       |     sys.exc_info()[2])
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 21, in import_by_path
app_1       |     module = import_module(module_path)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
app_1       |     __import__(name)
app_1       |   File "/var/www/ofsdashboards/common/middleware/login_required.py", line 7, in <module>
app_1       |     compile(reverse('ofsdashboards.account.views.login').lstrip('/')),
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 536, in reverse
app_1       |     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 403, in _reverse_with_prefix
app_1       |     self._populate()
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 267, in _populate
app_1       |     for pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 365, in url_patterns
app_1       |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 360, in urlconf_module
app_1       |     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
app_1       |     __import__(name)
app_1       |   File "/var/www/ofsdashboards/urls.py", line 33, in <module>
app_1       |     url(r'^homes/', include('ofsdashboards.homes.urls')),
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 26, in include
app_1       |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
app_1       |     __import__(name)
app_1       |   File "/var/www/ofsdashboards/homes/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
app_1       |     from .dashboard import views as dashboard_views
app_1       |   File "/var/www/ofsdashboards/homes/dashboard/views.py", line 17, in <module>
app_1       |     from ofsdashboards.common.react_renderer import render
app_1       |   File "/var/www/ofsdashboards/common/react_renderer.py", line 2, in <module>
app_1       |     import zerorpc
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
app_1       |     from .socket import *
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/socket.py", line 27, in <module>
app_1       |     from .events import Events
app_1       |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 31, in <module>
app_1       |     import gevent.coros
app_1       | ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing module ofsdashboards.common.middleware.login_required: "No module named coros"
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a Docker error, but rather just a basic Python error. It looks like the most recent version of gevent that you're using (based on the pip install in your dockerfile) likely moved the location of where the coros module is expected compared to where your source code expects it. See this: https://github.com/HelloZeroNet/ZeroNet/issues/720

Comment: Keep in mind that it's really easy during "migration to docker" to assume that Docker is the culprit in many of these situations. In my experience, migrating applications to Docker actually reveals issues that existing environments have been covering up for a long time. Don't get stuck in thinking that Docker broke your application :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traceback shows that `zerorpc` 0.4.4 is trying to import `gevent.coreos`, which [was removed in gevent 1.2](http://www.gevent.org/whatsnew_1_2.html#what-s-new-in-gevent-1-2).

Eventually, you want to upgrade `zerorpc` to a newer version that doesn't try to import `gevent.coreos`, but that may require further dependency/code changes.

A more minimal change would be to try installing `gevent<1.2` instead.